# Java DateTime output formatter equivalent to Calender.getInstance method

Tags: java, datetime

I am trying to replace old java Date with new DateTime. I am running the below code to check various formats:

```
public class MyMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Date date     = new Date();
        Date calender = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
        LocalDate ld  = LocalDate.now();
        LocalTime lt  = LocalTime.now();
        LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.now();
        ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.now();

        DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDateTime(FormatStyle.FULL);
        
        System.out.println("Date          :: " +date);
        System.out.println("Calender      :: " +calender);
        System.out.println("LocalDate     :: " +ld);
        System.out.println("LocalTime     :: " +lt);
        System.out.println("LocalDateTime :: " +ldt);       
        System.out.println("ZonedDateTime :: " +dtf.format(zdt));
        
    }
}
```

This is the output I got :

```
Date          :: Fri Aug 27 13:21:29 IST 2021
Calender      :: Fri Aug 27 13:21:29 IST 2021
LocalDate     :: 2021-08-27
LocalTime     :: 13:21:29.449
LocalDateTime :: 2021-08-27T13:21:29.449
ZonedDateTime :: Friday, 27 August, 2021 1:21:29 PM IST
```

I want to format the output for `LocalDateTime/ZonedDateTime` in such a way that it is equivalent to the `Calender` output. But I am unable to achieve that. Can someone help.

This is what I wish to get the output as : `Fri Aug 27 13:21:29 IST 2021`

Comment: Well, you do realize you can pass different styles to `DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDateTime()`, and that you can also create one with a custom pattern with [`ofPattern`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ofPattern(java.lang.String,java.util.Locale))?

Comment: Comparing the answers, if we want it the same as what `Date.toString()` produces (without having understood why you think you want that), (1) no comma after `EEE` (2) two `dd` for two-digit day of month (3) one pattern letter `y` for year of era in just as many digits as the year takes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to define a pattern for this specific output:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    // take the current moment in time in the desired zone
    ZonedDateTime now = ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("Asia/Kolkata"));
    // then print a formatted String
    System.out.println(now.format(
            DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEE, MMM dd HH:mm:ss z uuuu",
                                        Locale.ENGLISH)
        )
    );
}
```

Defining the zone explicitly is probably not necessary on your system since it has the desired zone (mine one is different, so I had to do it).

However, the output of this was (some moments ago):

```
Fri, Aug 27 13:38:22 IST 2021
```

Answer (score 3):

```
DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy", Locale.US);

System.out.println("LocalDateTime :: " + ldt.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).format(dtf));
System.out.println("ZonedDateTime :: " + dtf.format(zdt));
```

Answer (score 2):

This formatter should do the work

```
DateTimeFormatter dtf2 = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("E MMM d HH:mm:ss z y");
```

Just use this formatter instead the one you made.
[Here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) you can find a comprehensible list of what you can do with Java time and date formats.